# Why are the questions on this external poll wrapping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've tried short text answers but they still wrap to a new line instead of remaining in-line with each radio button. Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Wx5mM/2/

Complete code :

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".pds-pd-link").hide();
        $(".a2a_dd.pds-share").hide();
      });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6343621.js"></script>
<noscript><a href="http://polldaddy.com/poll/6343621/">New Poll</a></noscript>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After inspecting with the developer tools in IE i found out that the `label` for the answer is having a fixed `width` of `250px` because of which the content is overflowing to the new line. Just add the below css style to your style sheet, it should solve your problem.

```
.pds-input-label{
  width: auto!important
}
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rutwik/uNbcr/)

Comment: Do not use `!important` if you can avoid it - as it completely eliminates the possibility of any further overrideability/theming/skinning etc.. Simply specifying `width: auto` will fix the issue.

Comment: Tried `width: auto` without `!important` but didn't work. That's the reason i had to add `!important` . Point taken.

Comment: You are right. In this case, the content comes from another source and `!important` is pretty much unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
.pds-answer label{
    color: #333;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 150%;
    position: relative;
}
```

with:

```
.pds-answer label{
    color: #333;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 150%;
    position: relative;
    width: auto; <-- add this
}
```

inside the `<style type="text/css" id="poll_style6343621">` tag